# How to Analyze App Performance in Xamarin Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

First off, I'm new to Xamarin. I've build my app and now I'm trying to analyze my app's performance especially how long it takes for a specific task to be done.

I don't really understand about profiling documentation provided by Visual Studio

Anyone know how to start?

Comment: Use Xamarin profiler with Enterprise 2019

Comment: Hi , the Xamarin Profiler has a number of instruments available for profiling — Allocations, Cycles, and Time Profiler. You can have a look at this [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=windows) .

Comment: Is there any alternative rather than using Xamarin Profiler, i'm using Community Edition and those feature is not available

Comment: @Damar I think there will be some third party tools to do it but I know less about them . You can have a look at [this]( https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/147948/firebase-performance-monitoring-sdk-for-xamarin-forms) ,maybe helpful .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Microsoft Tools

The official tool to use is the [Xamarin Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?WT.mc_id=social-stackoverflow-bramin).

However, it is not free and is only available with a [Visual Studio Enterprise](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/?WT.mc_id=social-stackoverflow-bramin) account:

> You will need to be a Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber to unlock this feature in either Visual Studio Enterprise on Windows or Visual Studio for Mac on a Mac.

### Apple/Google Tools

You can also use the native tools, which are free.

The downside is that their tools don't know how to interpret .NET code. This means that it will help you discover a memory leak, but it can't tell you which line of code in C# is causing it.

#### iOS & macOS Apps

- Apple provides [Instruments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/using-instruments-to-detect-native-leaks-using-markheap?WT.mc_id=social-stackoverflow-bramin)

#### Android Apps

- Google provides [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)